# arcpy.da.UpdateCursor - How to update last column from Field Name List?

Tags: python, arcpy

examples:

```
for field in arcpy.ListFields(fc):
    if field.name != 'Hi': 
        arcpy.AddField_management(fc, 'Hi', 'FLOAT')
    else:
        print "kolona Hi vec postoji"

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, (fieldNameList)) as cursor:

    for row in cursor:

                hi = sum(np.array([row[i]/(sum([row[i] for i in range(len(fieldNameList))])) for i in range(len(fieldNameList))])**2)
                row[14] = hi # row[LAST] = hi ?????

                cursor.updateRow(row)

    del row
    del cursor
```

That instead of row[14] use the last column of the defined list?
examples:

```
row[last] = hi
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the last element list selector used in Python:

```
row[-1] = hi
```

Comment: Thanx @Richard Morgan... I solved... great..